# i've capture image and somehow the result its rotated to landscape image in android studio and im trying to integrate it with API i just dont know why

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What I need is :
I want to capture image and save it (I give the path) after that i want to send it to API i've already make it

What the issue here :
the result on image just keep rotating to 90 degree its not just a landscape from i've try it to take photo to landscape mode and its keep going to 90 degree rotation

what is done :
well somehow the image itself could send it to API

here is code i use to take a picture and somehow its rotated to 90 degree

```
private void takeCaptureCam(int statusSet) {
    if (statusSet == 0) {
        statusTakeImage = 0;
    } else if (statusSet == 1) {
        statusTakeImage = 1;
    } else if (statusSet == 2) {
        statusTakeImage = 2;
    }
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.    getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);


            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("currentPhotoPath",currentPhotoPath);

    return image;
}
```

here is the code to show the result i just dont know where part made it rotated automatically and i dont know how to explain it

```
private void takeCaptureCam(int statusSet) {
    if (statusSet == 0) {
        statusTakeImage = 0;
    } else if (statusSet == 1) {
        statusTakeImage = 1;
    } else if (statusSet == 2) {
        statusTakeImage = 2;
    }
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.    getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);


            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    Log.e("currentPhotoPath",currentPhotoPath);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Why did you post same code twice?

Comment: did it occur on android 10+...?

Answer (score 0):

get file's uri and then

```
 var rotatedBitmap: Bitmap
 val cr: ContentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
 cr.openInputStream(uri).use { input ->
     rotatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
 }
 rotatedBitmap = ExifUtil.rotateBitmap(uri.path.toString(), rotatedBitmap)
```

once you get the bitmap after rotation you can save it to file or display it in view.

```
fun rotateBitmap(src: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
    try {
        val orientation = getExifOrientation(src)
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
            return bitmap
        }
        val matrix = Matrix()
        when (orientation) {
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL -> matrix.setScale(-1F, 1F)
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> matrix.setRotate(180F)
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL -> {
                matrix.setRotate(180F)
                matrix.postScale(-1F, 1F)
            }
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE -> {
                matrix.setRotate(90F)
                matrix.postScale(-1F, 1F)
            }
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> matrix.setRotate(90F)
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE -> {
                matrix.setRotate(-90F)
                matrix.postScale(-1F, 1F)
            }
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> matrix.setRotate(-90F)
            else -> return bitmap
        }
        return try {
            val oriented: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bitmap,
                0,
                0,
                bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(),
                matrix,
                true
            )
            bitmap.recycle()
            oriented
        } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            bitmap
        }
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return bitmap
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getExifOrientation(src: String): Int {
    var orientation: Int = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED
    Log.e("src", src)
    try {
        val exif = ExifInterface(src)
        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, orientation)
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return orientation
}
```